# How to merge/ integrate geojson files to get either as shp/json

Tags: java, python, json, ubuntu

I have about 100 json files (in which each consisting with geometry and other details).

I would like to merge those files to get a single file...

I am new to java/python..

Step-by-step procedure needed to me to achieve this.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please read how to ask good questions. Its all about what code you have tried so far? and what is not woking.

Comment: Do you want java code or python code?

Comment: Dipak Thoke, I prefer JAVA